# ¿Cómo deshabilitar items de combobox luego de ser seleccionados?

Tags: extjs

Estoy trabajando con **Extjs**, y estoy haciendo un filtro en un `combobox`, para que, cuando agregue un ítem del listado, desaparezca de la lista y luego de agregarlo en mi `grid`que el combo se limpie para así evitar que se agregue de nuevo, ya que ahora en mi código (abajo lo pondré), agrego el ítem, pero luego de agregarlo, se mantiene en el combo aunque haya desaparecido del listado, y si escojo otro, y lo agrego, luego me vuelve a aparecer el que ya había agregado (no debería pasar eso).

**Código:**

```
onAddClick: function() {
        var me = this,
        combo = me.down('[name=comboboxEventosScoreType]'),
        value = combo.validate();

        if (value === true) {
            var store = combo.getStore();
            var data = combo.valueModels[0].raw,
            grid = me.down('[name=gridEventosScoreType]'),
            rec = new Events.model.grid.ScoreType(data);
            var storeGrid = grid.getStore();

            storeGrid.insert(0, rec);   

            var fl = new Ext.util.Filter({
                filterFn: function (item) {
                    console.log(data.uuid);
                    console.log(item);
                    return item.data.uuid != data.uuid;
                }
            })

            store.clearFilter();
            store.filter([fl]);
    }
} ...
```

[a continuación insertaré una fotografía del ejemplo, para ver gráficamente de que hablo]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Pasos según número en foto de ejemplo.

1. Escojo el primer ítem.
2. Agrego el primer ítem escogido.
3. Al momento de abrir el listado del `combo`para agregar otro, el
   field del `combobox`sigue con el primer ítem agregado, eso se quiere
   evitar.
4. Agrego el segundo ítem escogido.
5. Al momento de abrir el listado del `combo`para agregar otro, el
   field del `combobox`sigue con el segundo ítem agregado, eso se
   quiere evitar, además, sigue apareciendo el primero agregado en el
   listado.

Supongo que para cada ítem que ya he agregado, debería de tener un listado guardado en alguna variable de los `uuid` para saber cual se agrego y cual no para que no vuelva a aparecer en el listado, no? alguien sabe como hacer eso? , agradeceré mucho vuestra ayuda!

Answer (score 2):

Lo que debes hacer es eliminar el item del store del combo, al igual que estás modificando el store del grid añadiendo uno, el del combo debe ser modificado eliminando el que ya has añadido. El filtro únicamente hace eso, filtra los resultados para una búsqueda por ejemplo, sin modificar el origen de datos.

Aquí tienes un ejemplo que he realizado de un caso positivo funcionando, no lo tomes como dogma ya que hay algunas cosas mal hechas para que funcione y presentar el ejemplo de forma rápida (como asignar id a los componentes, no se debe hacer):

https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/1c67

En el ejemplo sólo se ve el caso de pasar del combo al grid, el caso del grid al combo es similar, eliminas el record del store del grid y se lo asignas al store del combo.

Comment: Puedes escribir un ejemplo de código de como hacerlo?

Comment: @devconcept Ya lo he añadido ! espero que se entienda fácil

Comment: Si te resultó útil esta respuesta, márcala como válida